# jquery mouseover and mouseout needs to work for specific element

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="hot_post">
<header>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/hot_post.png" alt="hot post"></li>
        <li><h1>Hot Post</h1></li>
    </ul> 
</header>
<div class="hot_post_list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="hot_post_single">
                <a href="" class="hot_post_thumbnail"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/83/83" alt="post title"></a>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40" alt="autor_avatar" class="hot_post_avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="hot_post_title">This is post for wordrpess</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="hot_post_single">
                <a href="" class="hot_post_thumbnail"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/83/83" alt="post title"></a>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40" alt="autor_avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="hot_post_title">This is post for wordrpess</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="hot_post_single">
                <a href="" class="hot_post_thumbnail"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/83/83" alt="post title"></a>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40" alt="autor_avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="hot_post_title">This is post for wordrpess</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my code. By default, "hot_post_title" is hidden. But I want to display "hot_post_title" when I hover over on "hot_post_thumbnail". If I try to display this by this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".hot_post_thumbnail").mouseover(function() {
        $("hot_post_title").css("display","block");
    });

    $(".hot_post_thumbnail").mouseout(function() {
        $("hot_post_title").css("display","none");
    });

});
```

Showing all of the "hot_post_title" within `ul`. I like to show only one own "hot_post_title" within `<li></li>`. For example if I mouse over the first `<li>` ".hot_post_thumbnail" I like to show first "hot_post_title" within first `<li>`. Then second for second. Third for third. Not all at a time. Please help me to do it (using jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $(this) instead of global class, which will obviously affect all items with that class. By using THIS you are targeting specific item that was hovered.

```
  $(".hot_post_thumbnail").mouseover(function(){
     $(this).parent().siblings(".hot_post_title").css("display","block");
  });

  $(".hot_post_thumbnail").mouseout(function(){
     $(this).parent().siblings(".hot_post_title").css("display","none");
  });
```

Copy pasting this should do the trick.

To set delay effect use show() instead.

```
  $(".hot_post_thumbnail").mouseover(function(){
     $(this).parent().siblings(".hot_post_title").show("100");
  });

  $(".hot_post_thumbnail").mouseout(function(){
     $(this).parent().siblings(".hot_post_title").hide("100");
  });
```

Use css when you want to set css settings instantly.

Comment: Thanks @salivan. It is working great. How can I set delay effect like .show(1000)

Comment: @user3019943 use `.finish().toggle(400);` see http://jsfiddle.net/UBWFJ/2/ or see my answer for better way implementing HOVER... ;)

Comment: @user3019943 use that instead of css version.

Comment: you have to stop animation in some way or it become buggy if user mouve quickly the mouse over

Answer (score 1):

Using `hover` in/out handler and `toggle()` method:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UBWFJ/2)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hot_post_thumbnail").hover(function(){
     $(this).closest('li').find(".hot_post_title").finish().toggle(400);
  });    
});
```

Add duration for toggle() effect.

Comment: I like this method +1.

Comment: I also like to show ".hot_post_avatar" like this way. How can I do this at a time. Like to show .hot_post_avatar and .hot_post_title at a time. How can I do it ?

Comment: add it to selector: http://jsfiddle.net/UBWFJ/4/  (use stop() instead of finish())

Answer (score 0):

you can use method `show()` and `hide()` 
try this:

```
 $(".hot_post_thumbnail").mouseover(function(){
         $(this).closest('li').find(".hot_post_title").show();
      });

      $(".hot_post_thumbnail").mouseout(function(){
         $(this).closest('li').find(".hot_post_title").hide();
      });
```

Comment: You're not solving the problem, which is that he wants to show/hide only the elements from the row he hovered on, not all of them.

Comment: stealing my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this)`

```
 $(".hot_post_thumbnail").mouseover(function(){
     $(this).parent().next(".hot_post_title").show();
  });

  $(".hot_post_thumbnail").mouseout(function(){
     $(this).parent().next(".hot_post_title").hide();
  });
```

Comment: You're missing `.` before the class name.

Comment: @Barmar I was the first to make that mistake, everyone took my answer I guess :D

Comment: @salivan - I didn't :)

Comment: @salivan Everyone took it from the question. :)

Comment: @Tip_Top at least I was the first with reading comprehension correctness.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're selecting every `.hot_post_title` each time you show or hide it.  Instead, you want to find the specific `.hot_post_title` applicable to the activated `.hot_post_thumbnail`.  Something like this:

```
$('.hot_post_thumbnail').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('.hot_post_title').css('display', 'block');
});
```

This starts at the thumbnail being activated, traverses up to a common parent (the `li` element, and then finds the `.hot_post_title` within that `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
$(".hot_post_thumbnail").hover(function () {
    $(this).closest("li").find(".hot_post_title").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).closest("li").find(".hot_post_title").hide();
});
```

Hide titles.

CSS:

```
.hot_post_title {
    display:none;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/srswG/)

Answer (score 0):

use closest it will search all handle that you look and will work great for you

```
$('handle').closest('li').find('handle').show();
```